# Beats by Dre microphone not showing up

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth, microphone, headphones, headset

My Beats by Dre mic is not working with my new Ubuntu 20.04. I can't even see it in the settings. I just see the internal mic. Everything else seems to be working like the speakers and the button. Can anyone suggest what I can do? The headset is connected over Bluetooth.

Answer (score 0):

[Audio jacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phone_connector_(audio)) usually come in three forms: headphone jacks, microphone jacks, and combo jacks. If you look at your computer chassis and see more than one audio jack, it is most likely not a combo jack, and you will need a [combo splitter](https://www.ebay.com/itm/174389037385).

As the names imply, headphone jacks will only detect headphones, microphone jacks will only detect microphones, and combo jacks can detect both at once (like a headset with a built-in microphone). If you plug a headset into a headphone-only jack, the headphones will work fine, but the microphone will not actually connect to anything inside the computer.

If you haven't in the past used a headset or microphone with that particular audio jack, it's entirely possible that it is not a combo jack at all. You can get an [adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B089NJPSXN) to add a combo jack to your system to use with your headset (keywords: "usb to combo jack").

Comment: Hi @Dev. Sorry my beats are connected via bluetooth. I didn't try with the jack as I want to have it connected via bluet. to roam around comforably.